# Need help to fix CSS four-column table

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with my CSS four-column table.

When one of the pictures is shorter, it goes out of whack. (see screenshot)

This is the CSS :

```
#results{background:#fff;padding:0 0 26px}
.result{float:left;width:25%}
.result-cover{border:1px solid #ccc;margin:0 4px 8px;padding:0 0 6px}
.result-img{border:1px solid #ccc;height:auto;margin:9px;overflow:hidden}
.result-img img{display:block;margin:0;width:100%}
.result .row{background:#fff;font:400 16px/20px 'MdCn',Arial,sans-serif;height:18px;overflow:hidden;padding:0 10px;text-transform:uppercase}
.result .row.stripe{background:#f6f9fb}
.result .row:last-child{font-family:'BdCn',Arial,sans-serif}
.prop{color:#373736;float:left;width:40%}
.value{color:#0f92cb;float:right;width:60%}
```

This is my HTML snippet :

```
<div id="results" class="clr">
<div id="results-inside" class="clr block">
    <div class="result">
      <div class="result-cover">
        <div class="result-img"><img src="images/res.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <a class="result-title" href="#">31698-1</a>
        <div class="result-props">
          <div class="row clr">
            <div class="prop">Code1:</div>
            <div class="value">29A</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row clr">
            <div class="prop">Code2:</div>
            <div class="value">24A0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row clr">
            <div class="prop">Code3:</div>
            <div class="value">0</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row clr">
            <div class="prop">Code4:</div>
            <div class="value">627A</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Ideally all picture is allign nicely]

[image: but When one of the picture is shorter]
But when one of the pictures is shorter the alignment goes wonky.

Comment: Im not going to look but I will guess its because you haven't set a height.

Comment: Simply `clear` every 4th element using `:nth-child()` …

Comment: As I see it, you have 4 divs as columns with id="result"? You should only have one element having the same id.

Comment: can you give example of clear  every 4th element using nth-child? or any example using column count 4 ? I suck at this.. thx

Comment: there is only one ID=results .. the rest is class=result (without the s)

Comment: I can defined the height static (for example height:250px) but when the block is longer.. then it gets covered...

Comment: CBROE , I want to marked yours as answer.. I figured out how to use :nth-child() thanks!!! can you post your's as an answer?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue using :nth-child()
Thank you CBroe.

I realize :nth-child() may not work with older browser. 
But that is not an issue for my case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a div around your 4 blocks and float it left and give it a width of 100% that would clear each row.

Comment: or just give `.result` `width:100%`?

Comment: I don't think give .result that width because by the CSS it is the class for one of the blocks

Comment: the problem is this is dynamic. so it has as many of .result .. and the width:25% takes care of the 4 in a row.... So I don't know how to put a div around the 4 blocks.. since the 4 blocks is not statically defined

Comment: Well you can create the rows dynamically using conditional statements and a counter. Using nth child won't work in older browsers.